# Ограничение точками число

Tags: c++

Как сделать так, чтобы число ограничивалось каждые 3 цифры точками, например, 123.745.126 и если дробное число то, 123.745.126.74?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это делается так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

struct Facet: std::numpunct<char> { 
    char do_thousands_sep() const {
        return '.';
    } 

    std::string do_grouping() const {
        return "\3";
    }
};

int main() {
  std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new Facet));
  std::cout << 1000000000;
}
```

[numpunct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/numpunct/)
[locale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/locale/)
[imbue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/imbue/)
Если вам нужно это число сохранить в строку, используйте `stringstream`

Comment: А почему ты не используешь using namespace std; после объявления библиотек, так же короче получается

Comment: @Max, меньше проблем при выборе имен классов, функций, переменных. Можно использовать имена `cin`, `cout`, `sort` и т.п.